# D SEGFAULT (CORE DUMPED)

Tags: segmentation-fault, d

I made a program in D to generate the (n+1) first Stern-Brocot sequences. Let SB(n) be the (n+1) Stern-Brocot sequence. I store SB(n) into a file named "n.txt". SB(n) contains (2^n) + 1 elements.

The procedure is quite simple, we ask an integer n and we generate SB(0), SB(1) ... SB(n).
The problem is that when n >= 15, I get : "Segfault (core dumped)".

The code is :

```
import std.stdio;
import std.math;
import std.string;
import std.file;
import std.regex;

struct rational{
    int num;
    int den;
};
alias rational rat;

int main(){
    int n;
    write("n : ");
    readf(" %s", &n);
    SB(n);
    return 0;
}

void SB(int n){
    int cn = 0;
    File file = File("0.txt", "w");
    file.write("0/1\n1/0");
    file.close;
    while(cn < n)
    {
        writeln("Generating SB(",cn+1,").");
        File from = File(_cast(cn)~".txt", "r");
        File to = File(_cast( cn+1)~".txt", "w");
        string A;
        string B;
        A = chomp(from.readln());
        rat a = extract(A);
        rat b;
        to.write(A);
        while(!from.eof())
        {
            B = chomp(from.readln());
            b = extract(B);
            rat q = oplus(a,b);
            to.write("\n", q.num, "/", q.den, "\n");
            to.write(B);
            a = b;
        }
        from.close;
        to.close;
        cn++;
    }
}

string _cast(int n){
    string s;
    if (n == 0) return "0";
    int nb = cast (int) trunc(log(cast (real) n) / log(10));
    int [] num;
    while(nb >= 0)
    {
        num ~= n / 10^^(nb);
        n -= num[$-1] * 10^^(nb);
        nb--;
    }
    char [] c;
    foreach(i; num)
    {
        switch (i)
        {
            case 0 : c ~= '0';
            break;
            case 1 : c ~= '1';
            break;
            case 2 : c ~= '2';
            break;
            case 3 : c ~= '3';
            break;
            case 4 : c ~= '4';
            break;
            case 5 : c ~= '5';
            break;
            case 6 : c ~= '6';
            break;
            case 7 : c ~= '7';
            break;
            case 8 : c ~= '8';
            break;
            case 9 : c ~= '9';
            break;
            default : writeln("Bad symbol encountered : ", i,".");
            break;
        }
    }
    return cast (string) c;
}

int __cast(string s){
    char [] c = cast (char[]) s;
    int [] num;
    foreach(i; c)
    {
        switch (i)
        {
            case '0' : num ~= 0;
            break;
            case '1' : num ~= 1;
            break;
            case '2' : num ~= 2;
            break;
            case '3' : num ~= 3;
            break;
            case '4' : num ~= 4;
            break;
            case '5' : num ~= 5;
            break;
            case '6' : num ~= 6;
            break;
            case '7' : num ~= 7;
            break;
            case '8' : num ~= 8;
            break;
            case '9' : num ~= 9;
            break;
            default : writeln("Bad symbol encountered : ", i,".");
            break;
        }
    }
    num = num.reverse;
    int a = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < num.length; i++)
    {
        a += num[i] * 10^^i;
    }
    return a;
}

rat extract(string s){
    s = chomp(s);
    auto r = regex("([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)$");
    auto m = match(s, r);
    return simple(rat(__cast(m.captures[1]), __cast(m.captures[2])));
}

rat oplus(rat q1, rat q2){
    q1 = simple(q1);
    q2 = simple(q2);
    return simple(rat(q1.num + q2.num, q1.den + q2.den));
}

int gcd(int a, int b){
    int r = 1;
    if (a == 0 && b == 0) return 1;
    if (a == 0) return b;
    if (b == 0) return a; 
    while(r != 0)
    {
        r = a % b;
        a = b;
        b = r;
    }
    return a;
}

rat simple(rat q){
    int g = gcd(q.num, q.den);
    return rat(q.num / g , q.den / g);
}
```

I have no idea why I get this Segfault. Do you know why?

My D compiler is LDC.

Core file :

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007ffff7a89742 in _aaInX (aa=<incomplete type>, 
    keyti=0x482e80 <TypeInfo_S3std8typecons18__T5TupleTAyaTAxaZ5Tuple.__init()>, pkey=0x7fffffffd610) at aaA.d:371
371             auto e = aa.a.b[i];
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00007ffff7a89742 in _aaInX (aa=<incomplete type>, 
    keyti=0x482e80 <TypeInfo_S3std8typecons18__T5TupleTAyaTAxaZ5Tuple.__init()>,    pkey=0x7fffffffd610) at aaA.d:371
#1  0x000000000044e44a in    std.functional.__T7memoizeS83_D3std5regex18__T9regexImplTAyaZ9regexImplFNfAyaAxaZS3std5regex 12__T5RegexTaZ5RegexVi8Z.memoize() (
    _param_0=..., _param_1=...) at /usr/include/d/std/functional.d:602
#2  0x000000000042f5aa in std.regex.__T5regexTAyaZ.regex() (pattern=...,flags=...) at /usr/include/d/std/regex.d:6461
#3  0x000000000042451e in dev.extract() (s=...)
    at /home/jonathan/Documents/Recherche/Fermat/SBs/D/Dev/dev.d:134
#4  0x00000000004238cb in dev.SB() (n=15)
    at /home/jonathan/Documents/Recherche/Fermat/SBs/D/Dev/dev.d:39
#5  0x0000000000423547 in D main ()
    at /home/jonathan/Documents/Recherche/Fermat/SBs/D/Dev/dev.d:17
#6  0x00007ffff7a82ab1 in rt.dmain2._d_run_main() (mainFunc=0x423500 <D main>)
    at dmain2.d:607
#7  0x00007ffff7a82a3a in rt.dmain2._d_run_main() () at dmain2.d:582
#8  0x00007ffff7a82b09 in rt.dmain2._d_run_main() () at dmain2.d:618
#9  0x00007ffff7a82a3a in rt.dmain2._d_run_main() () at dmain2.d:582
#10 0x00007ffff7a829ed in _d_run_main (argc=1, argv=0x7fffffffe148, 
    mainFunc=0x423500 <D main>) at dmain2.d:628
#11 0x00007ffff7a825a2 in main (argc=1, argv=0x7fffffffe148) at dmain2.d:383
#12 0x00007ffff6a64b45 in __libc_start_main (main=0x422cc0 <main@plt>, argc=1,  ubp_av=0x7fffffffe148, init=<optimized out>, fini=<optimized out>,rtld_fini=<optimized out>, stack_end=0x7fffffffe138) at libc-start.c:274
#13 0x0000000000423439 in _start ()
```

Comment: Did you run it through the debugger to see where it crashed? You could also load the core file into the debugger. For the record, seems to run fine for at least n = 25 on my system.

Comment: Same here; it compiles and run on n >= 15. Can you try it on another compiler, like dmd?

Comment: Can you get a stack trace for this crash? In gdb, type `bt`.

Comment: I have tested the code with DMD on Win7 and no Segfault detected. I will test with DMD on fedora soon.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the Fedora repository LDC?

If so, try a different D compiler, or try a different build of LDC. Fedora's LDC uses shared libraries, which Phobos does not support and which cause segfaults.